# Field Extension Embedding into Matrix Conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. How do we prove $L$ is a subfield of $M_n(K)$ (n by n matrices with entries in $K$) if and only if $[L:K]\mid n$?

My attempt:
I can't prove the forward direction.

For the backward direction, ($\impliedby$)

Suppose $[L:K]=\dim_K L=d\mid n$.
Then $L$ can be embedded into $M_d(K)$, which can in turn be embedded diagonally into $M_n(K)$. Thus $L$ is a subfield of $M_n(K)$.