# $K/F$ of degree $n \implies$ There is a ring homomorphism of $K$ into $F^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be an extension of the field $F$ of degree $n$, $K = \{c_0 b0 + c_1 b_1 + \dots + c_{n-1} b_{n-1} : c_i \in F \}$. Then for any $a \in K$, $\phi_a : K \to K : x \mapsto ax$ is an $F$-linear transformation of $K$, so the matrix for $\phi_a$ would be $A_a = \begin{pmatrix} \phi_a(b_0) & \phi_a(b_1) & \dots & \phi_a(b_{n-1})\end{pmatrix}$ where $\phi_a(b_k)$ is understood to be the column vector at the basis vector $b_k$.  I've shown that $\Phi : a \to A_a$ is additive, but how do you show that it is multiplicative?

The purpose is to show that $K$ is isomorphic to a subfield of the ring $F^{n\times n}$.

My attempt:
$\Phi(ad) = \begin{pmatrix} ad b_0 & ad b_1 &\dots & ad b_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$.  I've also tried working with a $2\times 2$ example and don't see where to take it.

Thanks.

### EDIT:

The answers in the comments don't answer my general question, they only give an example. Therfore, this question is *NOT* a duplicate!  In fact, I was already aware of the content of those answers!  (See above!)

Comment: Following question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674228/field-extension-embedding-into-matrix-conditions is related to yours.

Comment: Why was the gun jumped in marking this as duplicate?  Those answers don't even try to answer the general question.

Comment: I'll come up with an answer myself and post it here.  Just thought I could use some help...

Comment: @egreg: You've rushed to close this one, you shouldn't have done so: the OP knows about the left-adjoint representation, he asks how to prove that this is a multiplicative homomorphism - which is not shown in the "other" question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @AlexM.:  Perhaps the Question should then be edited by you or the OP, as the title and the second paragraph seem to make the issue "to show that $K$ is isomorphic to a subfield of the ring $F^{n\times n}$".  Indeed this "multiplicative homomorphism" is required to get a field isomorphism, and if there is a deficiency in the answer to the earlier Question, this is worth pointing out.  But the OP's complaint, "they only give an example", does not seem to properly credit the earlier work.

Comment: @AlexM. Proving it's a homomorphism is the easy part of the job. Better  answering the other question (or editing the existing answer). It's multiplicative because $\phi_{ab}(x)=(ab)x=a(bx)=\phi_a\circ\phi_b(x)$.